# Rails 5 associated table data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Inside the console I can access a related table by doing something like this.

```
@eec = ExpenseExpenseCategory.last

puts @eec.expense.payee.first_name
-> Charles
```

but inside a template if i have something to the extent of

```
<% @expense_expense_categories.each do |eec| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= eec.amount %></td>
    <td><%= eec.expense.payee.first_name %></td>
  <\tr>

<% end %>
```

which is set in my reports controller

```
def expense_expense_category_report

  @expense_expense_categories = ExpenseExpenseCategory.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {}
      format.js {}
    end
end
```

I get this error: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `payee' for nil:NilClass):

but,  If I call expense such as

```
<td><%= eec.expense %></td>
```

I get a relation Expense:0x007f9c8ad91b28> but I get the same error when trying to access it's attributes

```
<td><%= eec.expense.date %></td>
```

I get the error ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `date' for nil:NilClass):

How can I make certain I can access the methods like I do in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely that one or more of your categories does not have an expense associated with it. This sometimes happens to me if I have entered data and then added an association to a model.

This means that it is nil,and you are calling the date on a nil object, which causes your error.

You could check this in the console by running some test code like below

```
ExpenseExpenseCategory.all.each do |eec|
  if eec.expense.nil?
    puts "Expense category #{eec.id} has no expense"
  end
end
```

Comment: yeah. ran your code in the console. I have 4 entries without an expense. Seems like I need to add some destroy constraints on my model.